# How to delete child from Firebase with nested structure

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am writing an app whereby person X can make a post, and person Y can save it for viewing later. When person X deletes his post, I would like it to be also deleted from the saved items of person Y(or any other person who has the same saved post). I'm using firebase as the database for it and the structure is as such:

[Firebase structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfwlT.png)

```
"Y3keLEI354YJdaIC9te84TOflqn2" = uid of person X,
"192FDACA-84C8-49E0-A740-471922CB7C7E" = postid by person Y, and
Joe = person X
```

I have tried the following(using SwipeCellKit Pod):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {

guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

let delete = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { action, indexPath in
let savedDB = Database.database().reference().child("saved")
let selectedPost = self.postArray[indexPath.row]
let postid = selectedPost.postid
savedDB.child(?????).child(postid).removeValue()
}
configure(action: delete, with: .trash)
return [delete]
}
```

When person X deletes his post how do I code it such that the post is deleted from everyone who saved his post? I am stuck at "?????".

Seeking advice please.